# If not detecting nil inside block?

Tags: ios, cocoa, block, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have an AVPLayer with this observer

```
  __weak typeof(self.player) myPlayer = self.player;

  myself.timer = [myself.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval
                                                         queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)
                                                    usingBlock: ^(CMTime time) {

          if (myself.runAfterEveryFrame) {
            Float64 currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds([myPlayer currentTime]);
            myself.runAfterEveryFrame(currentTime);  // crashes here
          }

  }];
```

The player is on `self.player`.

This app loads movies in sequence. When a movie ends, the app created a brand new `AVPlayer`, loads the asset and stores it on `self.player`. Something like:

```
AVPlayer *newPlayer = ... init new player
// load assets, create new periodic observers, etc.
// new player is ready
self.player = newPlayer;
```

This works fine but after 3 or 4 movies played, it crashes on the line

```
 myself.runAfterEveryFrame(currentTime);  // crashes here
```

with `myself = nil`.

This is the question. There is this if

```
          if (myself.runAfterEveryFrame) {
            Float64 currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds([myPlayer currentTime]);
            myself.runAfterEveryFrame(currentTime);  // crashes here
          }
```

`runAfterEveryFrame` is a block of code that runs after every frame. if `myself` is `nil`, how is this two lines being executed? How can that be?

if myself is nil then `myself.runAfterEveryFrame` is `nil`, and the content inside the `if`should not run, but it is running and crashing inside the `if`.

Comment: How is myself defined? Is it a `__weak MyClass *myself = self;`?

Comment: Hint: Turn on all sensible warnings in Xcode, and the compiler will answer your question.

Comment: The documentation for `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:) says that the queue must be a *serial queue*. You are using a global queue, which is a concurrent queue. The documentation says that using a concurrent queue results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @newacct - you are right about that! Nice catch!!!! THANKS +1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a 2nd use of a weak variable inside an asynchronous block isn't safe so always cast the weak to a strong var inside the block. so self is captured weak but retained from the block

```
    __weak myType *weakType = self;

    //dispatch block

   //INSIDE block
    __strong myType *strongType = weakType;
```

Comment: BRILLIANT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I did not know I could strong a weak reference! THANKS

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `myself` is a weak reference like `myPlayer` (you didn't say in your question) it can be deallocated at any time, including inside your `if` block. To resolve, create a strong reference inside your block:

```
__strong typeof(myself) strongSelf = myself;
__strong typeof(myPlayer) strongPlayer = myPlayer;

if (strongSelf.runAfterEveryFrame) {
    Float64 currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds([strongPlayer currentTime]);
    strongSelf.runAfterEveryFrame(currentTime);
}
```

Also, you should be checking whether `CMTimeGetSeconds` returns NaN or infinity to be safe.

Comment: this is a dupe of mine ;) nicer written but a dupe